# MassTransit Kafka ConsumeException

Tags: apache-kafka, masstransit

How to catch and handle exception when an invalid json was sent?

> Confluent.Kafka.ConsumeException: Local: Value deserialization error
> ---> System.Text.Json.JsonException: '{' is an invalid end of a number. Expected a delimiter. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 |
> BytePositionInLine: 1.

I need to log an error and skip this message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way currently. This is a known issue, but no solution yet.